# term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, qt, qtconcurrent

Hi guys I really need your help
All I want to do is to scale an image and run it using QtConcurrent .. I followed the documentation exactly but still I can't catch where is my fault here is the code

```
void MainWindow::displayImages( QPixmap &image)
{
  image = image.scaled(100,100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation); 
}
void MainWindow::showImages()
{
  QList <QPixmap> images ;
  foreach(imageName,imageList)
  {
    imageNames.push_back(imageName.toStdString());
    image.load(imageName,"4",Qt::AutoColor);
    images.push_back(image);
  }
  QtConcurrent::map(images,&MainWindow::displayImages);
}
```

this code doesn't compile it keeps giving me the error

```
   1>c:\qt\4.7.1\src\corelib\concurrent\qtconcurrentmapkernel.h(73): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>          c:\qt\4.7.1\src\corelib\concurrent\qtconcurrentmapkernel.h(72) : while compiling class template member function 'bool QtConcurrent::MapKernel<Iterator,MapFunctor>::runIteration(Iterator,int,void *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Iterator=QList<QPixmap>::iterator,
1>              MapFunctor=void (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &)
1>          ]
1>          c:\qt\4.7.1\src\corelib\concurrent\qtconcurrentmapkernel.h(201) : see reference to class template instantiation 'QtConcurrent::MapKernel<Iterator,MapFunctor>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Iterator=QList<QPixmap>::iterator,
1>              MapFunctor=void (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &)
1>          ]
1>          c:\qt\4.7.1\src\corelib\concurrent\qtconcurrentmap.h(113) : see reference to function template instantiation 'QtConcurrent::ThreadEngineStarter<void> QtConcurrent::startMap<QList<T>::iterator,MapFunctor>(Iterator,Iterator,Functor)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=QPixmap,
1>              MapFunctor=void (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &),
1>              Iterator=QList<QPixmap>::iterator,
1>              Functor=void (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &)
1>          ]
1>          c:\main\work\extend3d\git\square-marker-tools\bundleadjustment\mainwindow.cpp(307) : see reference to function template instantiation 'QFuture<void> QtConcurrent::map<QList<T>,void(__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &)>(Sequence &,MapFunctor)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=QPixmap,
1>              Sequence=QList<QPixmap>,
1>              MapFunctor=void (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(QPixmap &)
1>          ]
```

Comment: What line number and is this the actual code (`...`) ?

Comment: I added the exact error I get please check it out

Comment: Now the edits are complete you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Notice the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtconcurrentmap.html#map):

> QtConcurrent::map(), QtConcurrent::mapped(), and
>   QtConcurrent::mappedReduced() accept pointers to member functions.
>   **The member function class type must match the type stored in the sequence**

Rephrasing it, in your case **you can only use** member functions of the `QPixmap` class.

You could however achieve what you want by making the `displayImage` function external:

```
void displayImages( QPixmap &image)
{
  image = image.scaled(100,100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation); 
}
void MainWindow::showImages()
{
  QList <QPixmap> images ;
  foreach(imageName,imageList)
  {
    imageNames.push_back(imageName.toStdString());
    image.load(imageName,"4",Qt::AutoColor);
    images.push_back(image);
  }
  QtConcurrent::map(images,displayImages);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
void displayImages( QPixmap &image)
{
  image = image.scaled(100,100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation); 
}
```

and

```
QtConcurrent::map(images,displayImages);
```

The issue is that you pass a reference to a function when calling `map`, and a member function need the referenced object.

**Edit**
To be part of main window declare the function static, and call :

```
QtConcurrent::map(images,&QMainWindow::displayImages);
```

Comment: I tried that as well but it gives me a list of errors telling me that 3 arguments are expected and 2 provided. To solve this I tried passing iterators like this      QtConcurrent::map(images.begin(),images.end(),isplayImages); but I get and error telling me the opposite 3 provided 2 expected !!!

Comment: and the first change you are telling  me about is exactly what I'm doing .. or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok.. so you meant that it shouldn't be a part of the MainWindow so now it works thanks :)

Comment: it can be part of main window but it must be static. see edit.